# Is it a good idea to use repaint() as a game loop?

Tags: java-me, repaint

```
class MyCanvas extends Canvas{
    protected void paint(Graphics g) {
        //Process keyboard
        //Update movement/position
        //Draw
        repaint(); //loop
    } 
}
```

Until now I used the Canvas's `paint()` for the game loop, but I came across some article in the web that says that another thread should be used here 
Now I'm wondering if `paint()` is a good/safe place to process all the data.

So can I continue doing it like this?
Or should I make another thread for that?
I'm not sure of pros and cones of each so I'm not sure which method to choose but I got used to repaint method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use `paint()` that way, no.  `paint()` should be for painting ... drawing.  I would split your monitoring of user input, and game logic processing, outside that method.

Have you considered using the [GameCanvas subclass of Canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/game/GameCanvas.html)?

It gives you some nice double-buffering features.  You would create another thread, which would call your GameCanvas' `run()` method, where it would check for user input, update the game logic, then draw to the off-screen buffer, and finally trigger repainting of the on-screen buffer.

Something like this:

```
class MyGameCanvas extends GameCanvas implements Runnable {

    /** start this game! */
    public void start() {
        Thread worker = new Thread(this);
        worker.start();
    }

    /** run the game loop */
    public void run() {
       // Get the Graphics object for the off-screen buffer
       Graphics g = getGraphics();

       while (true) {
          // Check user input and update positions if necessary
          int keyState = getKeyStates();
          if ((keyState & LEFT_PRESSED) != 0) {
             sprite.move(-1, 0);
          }
          else if ((keyState & RIGHT_PRESSED) != 0) {
             sprite.move(1, 0);
          }

          // Clear the background to white
          g.setColor(0xFFFFFF);
          g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(), getHeight());

          // Draw the Sprite
          sprite.paint(g);

          // Flush the off-screen buffer
          flushGraphics();

          try {
             // TODO: of course, you might want a more intelligent
             //  sleep interval, that reflects the amount of time
             //  remaining (if any) in the cycle ...
             Thread.sleep(10);  //sleep 10 ms
          }
          catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Note that I put basically everything in the `run()` method, for brevity.  I'm assuming your game is more complicated, and would warrant splitting off separate methods for getting user input, updating logic, and then calling graphics/paint methods.  Those would all be called from `run()`.

### Usage

Start this in your MIDlet's `startApp()` method:

```
  MyGameCanvas gameCanvas = new MyGameCanvas();
  gameCanvas.start();
  exitCommand = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 1);
  gameCanvas.addCommand(exitCommand);
  gameCanvas.setCommandListener(this);
  Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(gameCanvas);
```

### References

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35833/Programming-2D-Games-in-J2ME
- [an example that shows a better implementation](http://j2megame.uw.hu/ch07lev1sec155.html), if you **don't** use `GameCanvas` and just use `Canvas`.
- [PowerPoint overview of Game APIs and looping](http://ktpng.com/mc/ppt/L10_J2ME_Game_API_01.ppt) , with code and general theory